# Lodash GET expected a function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following Lodash function

```
flow(find({ id: args.roleRateId }), get('chargeRate'))(
          args.roleRates
)
```

however, it doesn't work for what i need, inside the get i need to add `get('chargeRate', args.roleRate)` so it can get the `chargeRate` form the `args.roleRate`, but when i add this I do get 
`Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function`
Anyone has any ideea why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: The error is thrown by the `flow()` function, presumably because `get('chargeRate', args.roleRate)` returns something that is not a function. Your problem is that you have mixed up the arguments to the `get()` function. They should be the other way around, i.e. `get(args.roleRate, 'chargeRate')`

Comment: Also, this would not work because both flow and get don't return a function

Comment: So, what would be the correct order. I tried switching the params inside get but nothing happens.

Comment: @ChrisD If you get the same error after using the correct order for the arguments, that means that `args.roleRate.chargeRate` (or the return value of `find({ id: args.roleRateId })`) is not a function.

Comment: Are you also sure find returns a function.?

Comment: Find does but args.roleRate.chargeRate isn't. I get it why it doesn't work now, thanks Stack!
Is there anything else i can use to get the value of 'args.roleRate.chargeRate' for each entry (it's an array) ? In lodash i mean

Comment: get is the best bet,You could use the default to return a function and handle the return issue

Comment: @dhrDatt can you explain further, i am already using a get in here.. I am not very good at Lodash yet, so yeah..

Comment: I was suggesting to just pass a function as the default parameter which is the third I guess.But if all you want to do is find based on some property and then get a different property,I think you don't need flow at all

Comment: @dhrDatt I am not sure how to write this. I need a flow because i'm inside a ternary operator

Comment: Not sure ,some thing like this.?
let x = () => {
   let foundObj = _.find(globArr2,{id:1});
   return _.get(foundObj, 'roleRate.chargeState', '')
  }
    let b = _.flow(x);

Answer (score 0):

First you import `import get from 'lodash/get'`.

Then `args.roleRate.chargeState` would be got like `get(args.roleRate, 'chargeState')` or `get(args, 'roleRate.chargeState')`.

Comment: I have get imported, obviously . ```flow(find({ id: args.roleRateId }), get('chargeRate', args.roleRates))``` this fails

Comment: ```flow(find({ id: args.roleRateId }), get('chargeRate', args.roleRates))(
          args.roleRates
)``` this too